# variable doesn't update outside the function

Tags: axios, token

I have created a login service that is used to send API requests. After successful login I get token and save to local storage. I use this token to get user settings data. I am using it like this. I want to create a token variable outside the function so that it can be used by multiple functions. But it doesn't update every time I send request, so I always get invalid token. Is there any way I can configure the token to be reused without having to write it multiple times like this? Here is my code.

```
import Const from '../constants'
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '@/store'


class SettingService {
  getUserSetting() {
    const token = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + store.state.authToken.token
      }
    }
    return axios.get(Const.api_url + 'members/me/member-settings', token)
  }

  updateUserSetting() {
    const token = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + store.state.authToken.token
      }
    }
    return axios.post(Const.api_url + 'members/me/member-settings', store.state.setting.setting, token)
  }
}

export default new SettingService
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Axios Instance. Copied from official axious GITHUB url

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: Const.api_url,
  timeout: 1000,
   headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + store.state.authToken.token}
});
```

Then subsequent calls you will use.

```
return axiosInstance.get('members/me/member-settings')
return axiosInstance.post('members/me/member-settings', store.state.setting.setting)
```